Does Taylor expansion work near the boundary
Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain with $C^{\infty}$ boundary $\partial\Omega$ and $0\in\partial\Omega.$ If $u\in C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega}),$ can we apply Taylor expansion to $u$ near $0$ ? To be more precise, is there any $\delta>0$ such that for $x\in\Omega\cap B_{\delta}(0),$ there exists $\theta\in (0,1)$ so that
$$u(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\sum_{|\alpha|=k}\frac{\partial^\alpha u(0)}{\alpha!}x^{\alpha}+\sum_{|\alpha|=m+1}\frac{\partial^\alpha u(\theta x)}{\alpha!}x^\alpha$$  Here $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is a multi-index and $|\alpha|:=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n,\partial^\alpha u:=\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}u}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}.$
I came to this question when I was thinking the following:
Under the same assumption on $\Omega,$ if $u,v\in C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ satisfies $u(0)=v(0)=0,\nabla u(0)=\nabla v(0)=0$ and $u\geq v$ in $\bar{\Omega},$ then does it hold that $D^2u(0)\geq D^2v(0)$ ? (that means $D^2u(0)-D^2v(0)$ is semi-positive-definite)
It's clearly true if $0\in\Omega,$ since in this case we can apply the Taylor expansion directly. If $0\in\partial\Omega,$ I wonder it also holds and the reason may be related to Taylor expansion near boundary but I know nothing about the latter. Can someone help me?
